# ListViewCommandSetContext is not assignable to parameter of type ISPFXContext

Tags: spfx-extensions, pnpjs, spcontext

I followed this tutorial : [building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api)

And I installed the latest @pnp/sp (3.4.1) and according to the [docs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/concepts/authentication/#spfx-sharepoint) I should be able to use it as follows:

```typescript
const sp = spfi().using(SPFx(this.context));
```

But I get this compile error:

> Argument of type 'ListViewCommandSetContext' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'ISPFXContext'.   The types of
> 'msGraphClientFactory.getClient' are incompatible between these types.
> Type '(version: "3") => Promise' is not assignable to type '() => Promise'

Is it even possible to use @pnp/sp here?

**update**
A possible work-around could be like this (untested...):

```typescript
const ctx: ISPFXContext = {
  pageContext: this.context.pageContext,
  aadTokenProviderFactory: {
    getTokenProvider: () => this.context.aadTokenProviderFactory.getTokenProvider()
  },
  
  msGraphClientFactory: {
    getClient: async () => await this.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient('3')
  }
};

const sp = spfi().using(SPFx(ctx));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround (tested and verified) for this issue is to create a wrapper instance which implements `ISPFXContext` based on the **this.context.pageContext**:

```typescript
// Create a own context
const ctx: ISPFXContext = {
  pageContext: this.context.pageContext,

  aadTokenProviderFactory: {
    getTokenProvider: () => this.context.aadTokenProviderFactory.getTokenProvider()
  },
  
  msGraphClientFactory: {
    getClient: async () => await this.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient('3')
  }
};

// Use this context instead of the "this.context"
const sp = spfi().using(SPFx(ctx));
```